# Problem with Boot Camp and XNA 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, development, 64-bit

I'll try to be as brief as possible with my problem. Do not hesitate to ask for logs or information about my computer and/or the program.

I have a game that consists of a ship that navigates on space. A friend and I are programming this game. The problem resides in the execution and debugging of the program on my computer (MBP 15" running Boot Camp) the speed of the game is deeply accelerated and the color of space becomes a bright red instead of a black.

We have been trying a few things with the drivers (everything is updated to the most recent) and playing around with the video card (vertical synchronisation, anti-aliasing, tessellation, Anisotropic blah blah) to no avail.

I am running Boot Camp on a mbp 15" using windows 7.

OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 bit Visual Studio 2010 XNA 4.0

The graphics card is a AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series

This question was already asked on Stack Overflow without success.

Comment: You should add the name of the program you're using. That might make your question less ambiguous.

Comment: The program I'm using is called "Visual Studio 2010" with XNA 4.0. It is in the title of the question.

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer here since its a Windows related question on Mac hardware. But I would recommend checking your card and the profiles (Reach or HiDef) that you use. I know that XNA 4 changed a lot of things and how it deals with cards. Finally, which model MBP do you have (like year, etc).

Comment: @jmlumpkin yes I agree with you the model is a 2011 mbp. Bought in may. Ill check what you suggested and keep you posted.